# Nimbus Look and Feel with JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am making a download manager and i am using a `JTable`. In `JTable` to show `JProgressbar` i am using a table cell renderer when i apply a nimbus look and feel due to table cell renderer my program gives exception but without cell renderer table and look and feel working well.

My code for table cell renderer is:

```
public class TableRender implements TableCellRenderer {    
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, 
        Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
        int row, int column) {

        return (JProgressBar) value;
    }        
}
```

and for Nimbus Look and Feel is:

```
try {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
    | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
}
```